# How to get session id on Selenium webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Im using SauceLabs and I need the sessionId to get the Job Id there and use it to set pass/fail status during execution of the test. How can I get the session Id using python?

Comment: Just doing a cursory glance over at google, I found [this](http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_session) that might help you. Of course, if it doesn't... then I'm a jerk, and I apologize.

Comment: Yep, that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks though

Answer (score 20):

Found it!

The value of the Selenium Remote Webdriver sessionId can be retrieved by

```
self.driver.session_id
```

That value is used on SauceLabs to identify the Jobs (Job ID)

Comment: What is the context for 'self'?

Comment: it seems to be context.driver.session_id when in a @step, but not when in the environment handlers

Answer (score 0):

"driver.session_id" will get you the session-id of current session.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary').driver.session_id