# Performance testing with JMeter JSR223 sampler

Tags: python, jmeter, performance-testing, jython, jsr223

I'm doing performance testing with `JMeter Python` using `JSR223` sampler. I want to know the following.

> 1. How to connect to existing browser window?
> 2. How to calculate performance timing?
>      Suppose I have 10 steps in `Python` code. I want to calculate timing from step 3 to step 5.
> 3. How to call methods from one `JSR223` sampler to another?

Kindly help me with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the browser was triggered from Selenium you can [determine its sessionid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944745/how-to-get-session-id-on-selenium-webdriver-using-python) like:

   ```
   self.driver.session_id
   ```

   and then start another WebDriver instance providing the aforementioned session_id as the parameter:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url,desired_capabilities={})
   driver.session_id = session_id
   ```

   if the browser wasn't kicked off via Selenium - it's not possible.
2. You can use [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) to measure the cumulative execution time of its children

   [image]
3. You can put your shared logic into a separate .py file and use [sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239372/how-to-import-files-in-python-using-sys-path-append) to load it where required like:

   ```
   from sys import path
   path.append(path_to_your_shared_module)

   import YourSharedModule

   //call functions from the shared module
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Consider I'm placing an order in browser, and i want to keep each step in separate JSR223 sampler. Will JMeter automatically determine the browser session and execute selenium steps accordingly?